# In R, how to identify which row a value belongs to

Tags: r

I'm absolutely new to R...I really appreciate for you help!!! here is my question. I have a data set, which is about the weight gain of chickens feeding by different diet. I created a data.frame for all the data. I was trying to identify the ID for the chickens that gained the least weight. so I sort the data first: 
`sort(all$'weight.diff')` but I cannot figure out how to pull all the information out from the chicken that has the least weight gained. And I also would like to know how to identify the diet for the chickens that gained the most weight.

Here is an example of the data I have

```
X1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) 
X2 <- c('A','B','B','D','D','A','A','A','B','C','C','A') 
X3 <- c(126,114,128,120,68,106,112,163,109,158,117,83) 
X4 <- c(269,212,259,231,76,220,288,318,250,361,197,169) 
all <- data.frame('ID'=X1,diet=X2,'10'=X3,'20'=X4) 
all X5 <- X4-X3 
all <- data.frame(all,'diff'=X5) 
all sort(all$'diff')
```

Thanks!

Comment: also have a look at `?which`  Notice it has an argument called `arr.ind` which when set to TRUE will give you the row/col index of found values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some bugs in your code, I think you mean all$X5. You don't need anything after that.

Either two of these should work to pull out the info for the least weight gained.

```
all[which(all$X5 == min(all$X5)), ]

all[order(all$X5), ][1, ]
```

In order to get information from the most weight gained just add the decreasing = TRUE bit and then take the first row with only the column you are interested in.

```
all[order(all$X5, decreasing = TRUE), ][1, 'diet']
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to sort here you can use `which.min`:

```
all[which.min(all$diff),]
  ID diet X3 X4 diff
5  5    D 68 76    8
```

PS : to create you variable diff , you can do like this :

```
all <- data.frame('ID'=X1,diet=X2,X3=X3,X4=X4) 
all <- transform(all,diff=X4-X3)
```